# How can I strip common JPEG headers to send it as base64 string

Tags: javascript, image, base64, jpeg

I am using [LQIP](http://www.guypo.com/introducing-lqip-low-quality-image-placeholders/) technique to create blurred placeholder images just like [Medium](https://jmperezperez.com/medium-image-progressive-loading-placeholder/) does, using low quality and extremely compressed versions of the original ones.

I am already able to send the inlined images and do all the canvas blurring and it is working great. But I want to go a step ahead: Concatenate the never-changing JPEG headers from the image as Facebook does.

I was reading through my source code today and I saw that the beginning of all images are all the same:

```
data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDADUlKC8oITUvKy88OTU/UIVXUElJUKN1e2GFwarLyL6qurfV8P//1eL/5re6////////////zv//////////////2wBDATk8PFBGUJ1XV53/3Lrc////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAARCAAPAB4DAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAGAAAAgMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMBAgT/xAAhEAACAQQCAgMAAAAAAAAAAAABAhEAAxIhMUEEEyJRof/EABYBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAv/EABYRAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABEf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8Axs7ewwSRluKBoD3SYDCOOaiqhLsmJMc7qod46XCMp11umgY3AyOEM5HsVnGhbzttcYj5Y/fdMKiyCqkFf2rSU2xKOykaiaI//9k=
```

as this one

```
data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDADUlKC8oITUvKy88OTU/UIVXUElJUKN1e2GFwarLyL6qurfV8P//1eL/5re6////////////zv//////////////2wBDATk8PFBGUJ1XV53/3Lrc////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAARCAAOAB4DAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAGAAAAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMEAQL/xAAjEAACAgECBgMAAAAAAAAAAAABAgARAyFREiIxMjNhQYKR/8QAFgEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAC/8QAGBEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERITH/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AIFZj0qAvDVQk0a9yGtzZWZFWwvDpS7RWFfdfySGHusi9YVpR439MBYhBZwDGr5SQKA+JoOXVEc8p12lV6//2Q==
```

Notice the repeating pattern at the beginning?
How can I just send the raw JPEG data? Would it be too costly for javascript to concatenate it later on? It is just 500 bytes of string to deal with.

Comment: don't try.jpeg files have headers that define stuff like x/y resolution, color/b&w mode, etc... you don't want to strip that off

Comment: @MarcB, the images are controlled by me and all of them have the same resolution, always. It's guaranteed. Even this way couldn't I remove the headers?

Comment: What is the advantage of this technique vs. interlaced jpegs?

Comment: As long as you are manipulating images via JPEG, you could easily construct full base64 string just by concatenating the predefined fixed starting part with a part unique for each specific image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can, as long as you are in control of your JPEGs headers:

```js
header = "data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDADUlKC8oITUvKy88OTU/UIVXUElJUKN1e2GFwarLyL6qurfV8P//1eL/5re6////////////zv//////////////2wBDATk8PFBGUJ1XV53/3Lrc////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////";

var img1 = new Image();
img1.width = 200;
img1.height = 100;
img1.src = header + "wAARCAAOAB4DAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAGAAAAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMEAQL/xAAjEAACAgECBgMAAAAAAAAAAAABAgARAyFREiIxMjNhQYKR/8QAFgEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAC/8QAGBEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERITH/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AIFZj0qAvDVQk0a9yGtzZWZFWwvDpS7RWFfdfySGHusi9YVpR439MBYhBZwDGr5SQKA+JoOXVEc8p12lV6//2Q=="


var img2 = new Image();
img2.width = 200;
img2.height = 100;
img2.src = header + "wAARCAAPAB4DAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAGAAAAgMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMBAgT/xAAhEAACAQQCAgMAAAAAAAAAAAABAhEAAxIhMUEEEyJRof/EABYBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAv/EABYRAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABEf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8Axs7ewwSRluKBoD3SYDCOOaiqhLsmJMc7qod46XCMp11umgY3AyOEM5HsVnGhbzttcYj5Y/fdMKiyCqkFf2rSU2xKOykaiaI//9k=";

document.body.appendChild(img1);
document.body.appendChild(img2);
```

You could load your image's base64 within a (combined) ajax request to your server. Concatenating strings and assigning data URLs is pretty efficient, especially when you want to load them into a canvas afterwards anyways.